# How to get request query string from the URL

Tags: java, portlet

I am trying to extract the query string from the static URL from the browser using Java.
But when I use the `getQueryString()` method, it is returning the query string for the particular portlet.

For example: my static url looks like this */owner/?search&name=* and the portlet URL is */home/create* which can't be seen in the browser URL.

Is there any way to extract the query string from Static URL?

Comment: Which portal do you use ? This is something not standardized, it depends on the portal used.

Answer (score 0):

James,

You may try to use [PortletRequest.getParameterMap()](http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/javax/portlet/PortletRequest.html), returning a java.util.Map of java.lang.String,java.lang.String[] - as in the official JSR-286 spec

Check the link, there are some other methods to extract URL parameters and values.

Hope this helps,
Philippe